# Send html file with js scripting inside as mail attachment

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to send a html file document as an attachment within a mail, but my problem is  that when I attach the html file it seems that the script tags are being removed from the html file before being sent.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("192.168.0.13");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("test@email.com");
        mail.To.Add("test@email.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test email";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = "test email";
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment("c:\\test.html");
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        client.Send(mail);
    }
```

Is there a way to send html file attachments without being modified?

Comment: Try zipping the file and sending it as a zip. The html stripping may be part of the email server malware protection, and it could recognize the html attachment as potentially harmful, so it gets the script tags stripped. Zip files will not be affected by this particular validation

Comment: Yes, you might be right! I'll try zipping it. Thanks.